# How to know which firebase function is using the most CPU seconds?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have many firebase functions written in nodejs. Some of them are using a lot of CPU seconds and GB seconds and it's costing a lot of money.

How to know which functions are the ones which are causing those issues so I can fix it?

Comment: I'm not expert in Firebase functions, but I guess you could be able to go to Google Cloud  Console and to see your functinos with your metrics. You can use Cloud monitoring to create graphs on your function and detect the most used.

Comment: Label everything and enable exporting your billing data to BigQuery. You can then use SQL queries to see details on items you are billed for such as CPU seconds. https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/Labelling-and-grouping-your-Google-Cloud-Platform-resources.html